# How do I know what scripts do I need for what Ajaxtoolkit control in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering how do i know what scripts are required for what Ajaxtoolkit control?
for instance i know for Datetime control these are requried in the following sequence
as seen [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/22/asp-net-mvc-tip-36-create-a-popup-calendar-helper.aspx)

BaseScripts.js 
Common.js 
DateTime.js
Animations.js 
PopupBehavior.js
AnimationBehavior.js
Threading.js
Timer.js
CalendarBehavior.js

Answer (score 0):

For an ASP.NET MVC app, follow [these directions](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/22/asp-net-mvc-tip-36-create-a-popup-calendar-helper.aspx).

Note, however, that [the jQuery date picker](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/datepicker) is nicer.

Comment: i already have the datepicker working  
but i need to know how to work with other controls. in the same way..